# How Selenium UI test should run with Specflow?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automated-tests, specflow

In our company I have made a simple program with C# (.NET Framework) that scans through our website and clicks all the buttons and does some general operations like add columns to a table or filtering it.

As of now we are running the test from a Windows forms application and using extent for results.
The test runs in bulk - meaning that you can not test just one page :(

Lately there has been a demand for more complex scenarios. I have created several tests using SpecFlow
and I am wondering if these tests can be run from a UI application?
Is this even recommended? If not how can we make running the tests easier for people?
We want them to be able to only create/edit the features files and run the tests

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow uses the various unit test runner (NUnit, xUnit, MSTest, SpecFlow+ Runner) to get executed.
You can execute the scenario with the command line or with the test explorer as every other unit test.

Executing from somewhere else is not possible, as long as you don't want to implement your own unit test runner. And believe me, you don't want to do this.

Also, the project with the feature files needs to be compiled after a feature file is changed because it generates a code-behind file, that is needed.

---

Full disclose: I am the community manager of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: How would you approach a request to create a dynamic test tool.
Where general actions are coded and users can create scenarios (much like Gherkin) without having to recompile the application?

Comment: @IdoGada: Visual Studio is your GUI tool. You can download and install Visual Studio Community edition for free. You'll need to learn some C#/.NET development, but this is well worth the time if you are automating your tests. Way too big for a StackOverflow question, though.

Comment: What should I do if I want to implement the tests in a Jenkins pipeline?
We are building the docker image and then using docker compose to start the environment.
How can the tests run in that case? Just with NUnit?